# Codeigniter model access from a file which is located at root

Tags: codeigniter

In CodeIgniter HMVC, I want to access a model of user modules from the root directory.Actually, i want to access database, model and all the things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just manage a config item in `config.php`.That is `application/config/config.php` add a config item like this..

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    'modules/' => '../../modules/'  //referencing at your root having modules folder
);
```

**Note:** *It is not necessary that your folder must named as modules .You can named it as my_modules etc..*

Then create a folder `modules` in root folder and access every thing like you do in application folder.

Hope it works great.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have added this code on config file on application folder then i have created a folder my_modules and a file created a simple index.php file but when i run this file it shows 404.Plz tell me why?

Comment: you have to create controllers,models and views inside my_modules like you create inside application folders.

Comment: ya glad to help you.

Comment: One more thing that if i want to call all those things like model in a single php file then what should i do (Note: i won't use model,view,controller)

Comment: i don;t understand clearly what you want...some explain